# How does the Windows 10 emoji panel work?

Tags: user-interface, windows-10, hook

I want to create my own version of the Windows 10 emoji panel:

[image: Windows 10 emoji panel]

While I know how to disable the built-in panel, I do not know how to replace it.

- How does the emoji panel listen for <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>?
- How does it listen to text in the original input box, while eating arrow keys?
- How does it affect the formatting of text in the original input box, when available (by underlining the search query)?
- How does it know when an original input box is unavailable or unsupported, to create a pseudo-box to paste the emoji into later?
- Finally, how does it end up replacing text once an emoji has been selected?

I've looked at [WinCompose's hooks](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose/blob/f24bdbb49964133d45a6e4d0c4b02e40e082c944/src/wincompose/KeyboardHook.cs), as well as [its ways to send input](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose/blob/f24bdbb49964133d45a6e4d0c4b02e40e082c944/src/wincompose/Composer.cs). However, because a compose key isn't meant to show any progress, I've not been able to find examples of changing the formatting of and replacing extant text.